# Getting Configuration Error while running Selenium Webdriver through command line

Tags: selenium, command-line, selenium-webdriver

When i am running the selenium webdriver through command line then my test always skips and i get below as a output .

===============================================
Parallel test runs
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1

## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 2

Also not able to understand when i am running 1 testcase then why skips show 2 testcases .
Please let me know if someone already faced this issue and how to resolve this .

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in this post to give you a concrete response, It could happened for many reasons such as:

- A precondition in the setup method is failing, so the test cases which depend on this are being skipped
- The system after execute the first test case is in a failure state and it is producing an error in the teardown method and the test class is skipping the following tests

Comment: The suite runs perfectly fine when run through java . I have checked the setup and tear down method and its fine . The only reason i am not able to find this why configuration failure .  I have found a link where the person is also getting the same error -- http://qtp-automate.blogspot.in/2011/10/running-selenium-testng-test-from.html         Here if you see when he runs then also he is getting the same error .